# Condensing Python multiple re.sub() functions

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I have a list of strings "list_var" and I need to strip out some info.

For example:

Input:

> member: CN=UserID,OU=Expelaplop,OU=blap,DC=stup,DC=hiya,DC=chop

Output:

> UserID

Code is working, but looks a little gross. Any tips?

```
result = re.sub(r'member: CN=','',(re.sub(r'memberOf: CN=','',( re.sub(r',OU=Expelaplop(.*)','',list_var[x])))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it down. Still open to suggestions to make it shorter

```
result = re.sub( r"(member: CN=)|(memberOf: CN=)|(,OU=Expelaplop(.*))",'', list_var[x] )
```